# Disable mirroring for Google Drive Desktop but still allow syncing specific folders?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, google-drive-for-desktop

We have a Google Enterprise account. Our Google Admins have disabled `Mirror files` option because if every use enabled it, it would take up everyone's laptop storage space and we do not want that.

But now, users can't sync/backup specific folders on their computer. Is it possible to leave `mirror files` disabled but still allow syncing/backing up specific folders?

[image]

Comment: This appears to be a corporate IT issue and thus not in scope here

Comment: @John: I think it's a general problem with Google Drive Desktop. The web is full of private users complaining about the same thing.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan: It seems that this is impossible and is why many people ditch Google Drive Desktop and use third-party software to backup specific folders to Google Drive. Or move away completely to competing cloud storage companies.

Comment: It is a Google issue and for them to fix.

Comment: @John: No, it's a Google Drive Desktop app problem.

Comment: The point I make is that it is not a setting we can fix, so up to whoever is responsible for the app.

Comment: @John I did not know that it was a Google/computer issue. I thought it might be some setting/configuration which I couldn't find, hence why I posted here to see. :(

Answer (score 0):

For My Drive files, mark them to be [available offline](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375012): In File Explorer, open the Google Drive folder > Select the synced files or folders > Right-click >
Offline Access > Available offline

Google Drive desktop will keep them downloaded and synchronized with google drive.

---

Edit: Per Google Drive's [supported drive types](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/13401938), you cannot sync folders outside of your google drive with mirroring disabled:

- My Drive can be streamed or mirrored.
- Files from shared drives, other computers, and backed-up USB devices can only be streamed.
- Local folders or your desktop can only be mirrored.

Comment: `Settings > Preferences > Folders from your computer` won't work cause it is not accessible if `Mirroring` is disabled by Google admin in GCP. :/

Comment: Ah, that was not covered by the google document I found before, but I did find the table here which does say Google Drive does not support folders from your computer in "Streaming" mode: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/13401938